# Drop Internet Connection If VPN Drops

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I am running `OpenVPN` and want a way in `Ubuntu` to drop my wifi connection if `OpenVPN` loses connection.

Is this something that is achievable, and if yes, how would I do it?

Comment: You can configure firewall to allow connectivity only to VPN server ip and drop/deny the rest.

Comment: @AlecIstomin - How would I set this up?  I have never used the firewall in Ubuntu.

Comment: there lots of examples floating around, ie https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88034/set-up-firwall-with-iptables-to-only-allow-vpn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVPN has a `--down` flag to execute a command after the session was terminated. You could use that to drop your wifi connection: `--down "ip link set wlan0 down"` (assuming `wlan0` is your wireless interface).

Comment: Where would I add that command?

Comment: You should put that in your commandline arguments. But you should also be able to add `down "ip link set wlan0 down` in your openvpn configfile.

Comment: Would it be my client.ovpn file?

Comment: That can be the file, but I don't know how you configured your OpenVPN.